# How to insert a vector into a column of a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, vector, rmysql

In R, I have a vector, "myVector", of strings which I want to insert into a column, "myColumn", of a mysql table, "myTable". I understand I can write the sql query and run it in R using dbSendQuery. So let's figure out the sql query first. Here is an example:

```
myVector = c("hi","I", "am")
```

Let's insert myVector in the column myColumn of myTable, row numbers 3 to 5, here is the sql query which works except for the last line I have no idea:

```
UPDATE myTable t JOIN
       (SELECT id
        FROM myTable tt
        LIMIT 3, 3
       ) tt
       ON tt.id = t.id
    SET myColumn = myVector;
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Are you trying to insert **new** records, or update existing ones?

Comment: Unclear.  Please show us the table schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and the desired result of the operation.

Comment: is `id` in `myTable` an `AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`? Your update query shows that it is not, or that you have some other field on which you sort your table by default.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that I understand your problem correctly, I have two possible solutions on my mind:

**1. one column per element:** 
if your vectors are all have equal number of elements, you could store each of them in a seperate column. Proceeding from your example above, the table could look like this. (the size of the columns and whether to allow null values or not depends on your data)

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `element1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The statement for inserting your vector from above would be:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `element1`, `element2`, `element3`)
VALUES (1, 'hi', 'I', 'am');
```

Depending on how much elements your vectors have this approach might be  more or less applicable.

**2. Storing the vector as a blob:**
Another approach could be storing the vector as a blob. Blob (Binary Large Object) is a datatype to store a variable amount of (binary) data (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html). This idea is taken from this article: http://jfaganuk.github.io/2015/01/12/storing-r-objects-in-sqlite-tables/

The table could be created using the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myVector` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When inserting your vector you bind the variable to your query. As I am not a R specialist I would refer to this article for the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware, if MySQL support `Vector` data type, but you could design your table as workaround where `Vector` can be store in different table and will have relation with `myTable` as `1-M`.

This is help you to manage and retrieve details easily. So, assuming `myTable` is your table and it's existing design is :

```
myTable
-------
id
col1
vectorCol
```

So, you main table can be

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1  varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and table which will store your vector.

```
CREATE TABLE vectorTab ( 
    id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- in case ordering matter
    parent_id        INT NOT NULL, 
    value     TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES myTable (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: please explain more about the content of column `col1` in table `myTable` and column `value` in the `vectorTab`. thx

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is export your `R` vector as `JSON` using [`toJSON()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RJSONIO/versions/1.3-0/topics/toJSON) function for example:

```
myJSONVector = toJSON(c("hi","I", "am"))
```

Also create or alter `myTable` so that `myColumn` has the appropriate [`JSON Data Type`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

> *Attempting to insert a value into a JSON column succeeds if the value
>   is a valid JSON value, but fails if it is not:*

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (`myColumn` JSON);
INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES(myJSONVector); // will fail if myJSONVector is not valid JSON
// update query would be
UPDATE `myTable` SET `myColumn` = myJSONVector
WHERE `id` IN (3,4,5);
```

**In addition**
  you can make an `R` vector from `JSON` using function [`fromJSON()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.5/topics/toJSON%2C%20fromJSON).